# Positive semi-definite matrix proof

Tags: matrices, machine-learning, positive-semidefinite

Something similar came up in an old exam. Can you prove or disprove (with a counterexample) the following:

Let $k(x,y)$ be a symmetric function, with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $k:\mathbb{R}^{d\times 2} \to \mathbb R$

For $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let G be defined as:

\begin{equation*}
G_{x_1,..,x_n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
k(x_1, x_1) & k(x_1,x_2) & \cdots & k(x_1,x_n) \\
k(x_2, x_1) & k(x_2,x_2) & \cdots & k(x_2,x_n)  \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
k(x_m, x_1) & k(x_m,x_2) & \cdots & k(x_m,x_n) 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Now lets assume that for each two vectors $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ it holds that $G_{x_1,x_2}$ is positive semi-definite, with:

\begin{equation*}
G_{x_1,x_2} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
k(x_1, x_1) & k(x_1,x_2) \\
k(x_2, x_1) & k(x_2,x_2) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Does it follow that $G_{x_1,..,x_n}$ is positive semi definite for any $n$ vectors $x_1,..,x_n$ ?

I'm pretty sure this is not true but couldn't find a counterexample.

Remark : This would essentially mean that $k$ is a kernel and $G$ is the corresponding Gram Matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure the statement makes sense because $G_{x_1,x_2}$ is a map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$, while $G_{x_1,\ldots, x_n}$ is a map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$

Comment: Yes but $G$ is built from $k$, which maps to $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$ let $$k(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & x=y\\-1& x\ne y\end{cases}.$$  Then, if your $x_i$ vectors are distinct, your $2\times2$ matrices are all $\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$ and all the larger ones contain as submatrices the non-psd matrices $\pmatrix{1&-1&-1\\-1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1}$.

In this example the $k$ function is discontinuous.  But it is easy to find continuous $k$ that contain this same behavior at selected combinations of $x_i$ vectors.

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks!